# Extract data from another workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks.

In Workbook A, I want to find the value in cell A11 (sheet 'Data') in column A of Workbook B and then return the corresponding value in column H. THis value must be pasted into Cell C11 in Workbook A.

Workbook B must be opened and closed to extract this data without the user having to manually open it.

How do I use a VBA code to achieve this? Preferably variables are built in based on values in workbook A e.g. path, file name, worksheet name, column A in above example and column H in above example).

Link to Workbook A: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6ixr5ky4i2r6vw/Data%20extraction.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Usually at this point, I would make a macro that sorta did what I wanted to do, then dig into the code that it generates (ALT+F11 I believe is fastest) and modify that to suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MS Office Excel Professional Plus 2010.  As long as the user won't be storing file B where he can't access it again, Excel can manage this without the need for VBA.

In cell C11 in workbook A type "=" to begin writing a formula.  Now switch windows to workbook B and click cell A11 on sheet 'Data'.  Hit 'Enter' on your keyboard... the computer should return to workbook A.

The formula in C11 now should show the filename of workbook B and the cell reference.

Now's when the magic starts: Excel has made this formula into a "Data connection" and will work behind the scenes to keep this cell updated.  It may give you a yellow bar asking to activate automatic data updates, which you should accept.

Test and see if this method satisfies your requirement.  If workbook B is stored in a shared location, do more testing to see if that doesn't mess it up.

Good luck!